# HtmlAgilityPack - Only getting first row of data on an HTML file

Tags: html, vb.net

I am using HtmlAgilityPack for the first time and I thought I had my code correct, but I am only getting the first row over and over. Maybe my tags for the file are needing adjustment?

I am not sure how much more details I need to give to be able to get this question posted.

Here is my input file:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></head><body>
<table border="1" fontsize="-1" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="2">
<tbody><tr>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Record #</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Type</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Name</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Alias</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Address</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">City</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">State/Prov</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Country</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">ZIP/P.Code</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">League</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Gender</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">SKILL-A</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">SKILL-B</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">8BL AVG</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">RTG</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">EloRate</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">FARGO ID#</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">FARGO/R</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Flagged</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Email</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Day time #</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Cell #</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Carrier</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Ok to Text</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Add. Info</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Team Membership</font></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="center"><font size="1">56</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Player</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Test Player 1            </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Player 1    </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">                                        </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Houston                  </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Texas               </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">United States       </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Male</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"> 4(C+)</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"> 4(C+)</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">N/A</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">N/A</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">327</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">                                                                           </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">               </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">8325557474     </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Yes</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td></tr>

<tr><td align="center"><font size="1">74</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Player</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Test Player 2            </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Player 2  </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">                                        </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Houston                  </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Texas               </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">United States       </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Male</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"> 4(C+)</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"> 4(C+)</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">N/A</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">N/A</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">370</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">                                                                           </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">               </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">7135558974     </font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1">Yes</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="1"></font></td></tr>

</tbody></table>
</body></html>
```

Here is my code:

```
        For Each row As HtmlNode In hdDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tbody//tr")
                'Initialize fields
                strPlayerNo = ""
                strPlayerName = ""
                strPlayerEmail = ""
                strPlayerPhone = ""
                strPlayerAlias = ""
                strPlayerOKtoText = ""
                strPlayerCity = ""
                strPlayerState = ""
                strPlayerCountry = ""
                iCnt = 0

                For Each col As HtmlNode In row.SelectNodes("//td")
                    iCnt += 1
                    Select Case iCnt
                        Case 1
                            strPlayerNo = col.InnerText
                        Case 3
                            strPlayerName = col.InnerText
                        Case 4
                            strPlayerAlias = col.InnerText
                        Case 6
                            strPlayerCity = col.InnerText
                        Case 7
                            strPlayerState = col.InnerText
                        Case 8
                            strPlayerCountry = col.InnerText
                        Case 20
                            strPlayerEmail = col.InnerText
                        Case 22
                            strPlayerPhone = col.InnerText
                        Case 24
                            strPlayerOKtoText = col.InnerText

                    End Select
                Next col

                If strPlayerNo <> "Record #" Then
                    strSQL = "select * from tblplayers where playerno = " & strPlayerNo

                    dt = CreateDatatable(strSQL)
                    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                        strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblPlayers (PlayerNo,PlayerName,PlayerEmail,PlayerPhone,PlayerAlias,PlayerOKtoText"
                        strSQL += ",PlayerCity,PlayerState,PlayerCountry) VALUES("
                        strSQL += "'" & strPlayerNo & "','" & strPlayerName & "','" & strPlayerEmail & "','"
                        strSQL += strPlayerPhone & "','" & strPlayerAlias & "','" & strPlayerOKtoText & "','"
                        strSQL += strPlayerCity & "','" & strPlayerState & "','" & strPlayerCountry & "')"

                        strReturn = exeOledbExecuteNonQuery(strSQL)
                        If strReturn <> "" Then
                            Master.txtMsgText = "Error inserting players - Error:  " & strReturn
                            Master.txtMsgVisible(True)
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

            Next row
```

Thanks in advance.
Eddi Rae

Comment: `dim tableNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").FirstOrDefault() for each td in tableNode?.SelectNodes("//td").ToList() ... `

Comment: Thanks for the info Jimi.  Question, though.  Do I not use the "//tr" since I will be creating code to import into a SQL table for each row.

Comment: `dim tableNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").FirstOrDefault() dim trs = tableNode?.SelectNodes("//tr").ToList() for each tr in trs  dim tds = tr.GetChildElements().ToList() for each td in tds  Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText) next next`

Comment: GetChildElements doesn't exist as a command.  What else should I use?

Comment: That's an extension method you can find in the `HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors` assembly. It's a NuGet package. Install it and add a reference to this assembly, you'll need it. -- You can also write: `dim trs = tableNode?.SelectNodes("//tr").ToList() dim tds = trs.First().SelectNodes("//td") for each td in tds Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText) next`. But really you need that library and its extensions.

Comment: I added the HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors, but this is in C# code and I am using VB.  It is giving me an error of "NodeExtensionMethods.cs not found.  When I try to find the location, it gives me "C:\Projetos\HAP.CssSelector\HapCss\NodeExtensionMethods.cs" as the folder for the search.  I notice that your code has a "?" on the trs = tableNode?.SelectNodes.  I don't think that is supposed to be there?

Comment: 1. It's a Library, the language doesn't matter. 2. You're trying to step-into that code while debugging and you don't have generated the library's `.pdb`. Or the NuGet installation is not flawless. 3. The `?` [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (also known as *the Elvis*) is there on purpose and it's meant to handle the `.FirstOrDefault()` chance that no Elements are found.

Comment: Anyway, you can use the second snipped: `dim tableNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").FirstOrDefault() dim trs = tableNode?.SelectNodes("//tr").ToList() dim tds = trs.First().SelectNodes("//td") for each td in tds Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText) next`, this doesn't require any *extension*.

Comment: Thanks for being patient.  With the "?", it doesn't compile correctly with it there. I have tried all of your suggestions and I still just get the 1st row.  It runs through that 1st row several times, but I don't get any of the other data.

Comment: If the  null-conditional operator is not available, then you're using an old version of VB.Net (2013 or lower - this should be in the question, otherwise it's assumed that you're using a recent version). You can replace the operator with `If tableNode IsNot Nothing then ' The rest ... End If`The last snippet I've posted is tested with the HTML you're showing here,  `HtmlAgilityPack 1.11.31` and without `HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors`.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Studio Community 2017.  I am getting all of the TDs that are in the document, but I need to have it so that I get each individual row and read only the TDs for that row.  This is giving me ALL of the TDs on the document.  How would you program this way?

Comment: VS Community 2017 has a version of VB.Net that supports null-conditional operators, check the VB.Net version you're actually using.  -- That code snippet is doing exactly what you described.

Comment: Thanks!! I have it working!!  Here is the code that I am using  ---  
hdDoc = New HtmlDocument
Dim tableNode = hdDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").FirstOrDefault()
Dim rows = tableNode.SelectNodes("//tr[td]")
For Each row In rows
 Dim cols = row.SelectNodes("td")
 strPlayerNo = cols(0).InnerText
next row

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have found that works for me.

```
Dim hdDoc As HtmlDocument
hdDoc = New HtmlDocument
Dim tableNode = hdDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").FirstOrDefault()
Dim rows = tableNode.SelectNodes("//tr[td]")
For Each row In rows
    Dim cols = row.SelectNodes("td")
    strPlayerNo = cols(0).InnerText
next row
```

Thanks for your help Jimi!!